# Grails -Gsp - How to make Check-box checked based on the value of the field

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a attribute called `status` in my domain which is `String` type can have any one of  two values `Applied , NotApplied`

I have two check boxes to input this value. in my edit page i want to display these two check box.

If the value of  `status` is `Applied` then the corresponding checkbox must be checked.

my code

```
 <g:message code="publicRuleInstance.course.label" default="Applied" />
<g:checkBox name="status " value="${publicRuleInstance?.status }" />

<g:message code="publicRuleInstance.course.label" default="NotApplied" />
<g:checkBox name="status " value="${publicRuleInstance?.status }" />
```

but here both the checkboxes are checked.

there must be a way to check the value i.e if the status = Applied then that perticular checkbox must be cheched else it should be unchecked.

Is there any way to doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `checked` attribute to control the state of your checkBox as described in the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/checkBox.html).
Here you could add any expression to determine the state of the `g:checkBox`:

```
<g:message code="publicRuleInstance.course.label" default="Applied" />
<g:checkBox name="status " value="Applied" checked="${publicRuleInstance?.status == 'Applied'}"/>

<g:message code="publicRuleInstance.course.label" default="NotApplied" />
<g:checkBox name="status " value="NotApplied" checked="${publicRuleInstance?.status == 'NotApplied'}"/>
```

If you just want to allow one of the values - `Applied` **or** `NotApplied` a [g:radioGroup](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html) would be the better choice. With a checkBox the user could choose both values `Applied` and `NotApplied`.

Answer (score 2):

Value of checkBox should be boolean

```
<g:message code="publicRuleInstance.course.label" default="Applied" />
<g:checkBox name="status " value="${publicRuleInstance?.status =="Applied"}" />

<g:message code="publicRuleInstance.course.label" default="NotApplied" />
<g:checkBox name="status " value="${publicRuleInstance?.status == "NotApplied" }" />
```

Comment: Is there any hard code rule that saying checkBox should have boolean value?

Comment: No - `g:checkBox` could have any `value`.

Comment: It is logical that value of checkbox should be boolean.

Other question is how groovy will parse value you pass.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Truth

Comment: checked attribute must be a boolean, but value attribute can be any value. See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/checkBox.html